# Template not updating after calling a angularjs controller method

Tags: angularjs

I could not update the template after a search using a controller method.

I have a controller wich list data to a template, correctly if no search is performed. The data is retrieved from a service.

When i do search by month and origin the result after calling the search method **in the console.log is the right data**, but the html template **does not show this data it shows the non-filtered data**.

I try to return the $scope.data, or scope.apply, it did not work.

How can i update the template with the filtered data ?

The controller with the search method :

```
.controller('AcpCtrl', function($scope, ApiAcpFactory, $ionicLoading, $timeout, $http) {  
  $scope.data = null;
  $ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: true,template: '<p>Searching ...</p>'});
  ApiAcpFactory.getApiData()
    .then(function(result) {      
        var acp = {};
        acp.resultdata = [ result ];      
        $scope.data = acp.resultdata;      
        $ionicLoading.hide();
   })

   $scope.search = function(data) {
        $scope.data = null;
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.formData.month = data.month;
        $scope.formData.origin  = data.origin;
        $ionicLoading.show({noBackdrop: false,template: '<p>Searching</p>'});        
        ApiAcpFactory.getApiData($scope.formData)
        .then(function(result) {             
            $scope.data = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(' scope.data '+$scope.data);      
            $ionicLoading.hide();
       })
        return $scope.data;
    }
})
```

The factory :

```
.factory('ApiAcpFactory', function($http, $q, ApiAcpEndpoint) { 
  var getApiData = function(data) {    
    var q = $q.defer();    
    $http.post(ApiAcpEndpoint.url,data)
    .success(function(data) {
        q.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(error){
        console.log('Had an error'+error)
        q.reject(error);
    })
    return q.promise;
  }
  return {
    getApiData: getApiData    
  };

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason is that your changes are happening within deferred callbacks. Therefore AngularJS is not noticing that turn happening in its cycle.

You say you tried `$apply`, can you post what you tried?

This would be the proper use in this situation:

```js
$scope.$apply(function(){    
  $scope.data = acp.resultdata;  
});
```

This is all very nicely explained [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Comment: I am new to angularjs, i have tried before `$scope.apply($scope.data);`  the error was : Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress, i try also : `$scope.$apply(function(){    
  $scope.data = acp.resultdata;  
});` and get the same error message as above. The console.log show diferent data. Seems that the controller  run again the body of the controller wich makes the initial listing. I will try to separate templates and controllers, did not know if is the best way to handle this problem.

Comment: Using `http.post` in its simplest form just work´s, at the console.log i see the new expected data, and the template did not present the old data anymore. The only remaining problem is the ng-repeat duplicates, using track by $index makes it iterate over each character of the Json result track by item or any other data element also fires the duplication error message. The JSON data has the same structure of the initial listing wich works right.

Comment: Not sure exactly the issue, maybe you could paste what the error is. _However_ it sounds like this could be a solution or an explanation to your problem: http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/

Comment: Strange but the cause was a call to JSON_stringify, when i stop to use it the duplication error also stops. Would be good to have a way to track where the duplication  was.

Comment: I just stop using JSON_stringify and use instead : 
`var acp = {};`
`acp.resultdata = [ result ];`     
`$scope.data = acp.resultdata;`

Comment: I'm glad you've found a solution!